# Validate method returns false for a valid XmlObject

Tags: java, xml

I have a code snippet which is converting a Java Object to XmlObject, but when I use the validate method of XmlObject it returns false. Can anyone help in this where is the issue in this.

```
public void validate(UserAccount userAccountObject) throws SecurityServiceException, JAXBException, XmlException {
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserAccount.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JAXBElement < UserAccount > jaxbElement = new JAXBElement < > (new QName("", "userAccount"),
    UserAccount.class, userAccountObject);
marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, sw);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
XmlObject xmlObject = XmlObject.Factory.parse(xmlString);
if (!xmlObject.validate()) {
    logger.debug("Invalid XML Object.");
    throw new SecurityServiceException(MessageConstants.INVALID_XML_OBJECT);
}
```

}

xmlString

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<userAccount xmlns:ns2="http://gnw.com/ebd/service/domain/">
<ns2:ApplicationName>"ABC_APPLICATION"</ns2:ApplicationName>
<ns2:UserInfo>
    <ns2:UserId>"abc@gmail.com"</ns2:UserId>
    <ns2:FirstName>"First"</ns2:FirstName>
    <ns2:LastName>"Last"</ns2:LastName>
    <ns2:CompanyName>"DEF"</ns2:CompanyName>
    <ns2:Properties>
        <ns2:FieldName>"extend_validity_values"</ns2:FieldName>
        <ns2:FieldValue>"true"</ns2:FieldValue>
    </ns2:Properties>
</ns2:UserInfo>
<ns2:Password>"password"</ns2:Password>
```

Comment: could you share the xmlString you are using?

Comment: @vc73 updated the comment with xmlString.